# Dart enum with Template pattern

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

Is there a possible to use enum with Template pattern. Let's me talk about the scenario. I used the coding standard **PascalCase** with Enum, and the api returned the value is **CamelCase**, so that caused to be transform both to lower case to compare the `String`. I used the following code:

```
  static _moveStatusFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    String rawString = json['moveStatus'] as String;
    MoveStatus type = MoveStatus.values.firstWhere((value){
      return value.toString().split(".").last == rawString.toLowerCase();
    }, orElse: (){
      return null;
    });
    return type;
  }
```

`MoveStatus` is `enum`, and If I have a bunch of same data, I need to write almost the same code, again and again. So I imagine I could use template pattern to slove this, but couldn't find any example. Below is what I imagine, but I can't transform T to the enum, because `enum` is not a normal class.

```
  static _moveStatusFromJson<T>(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    String rawString = json['moveStatus'] as String;
    T type = T.values.firstWhere((value){
      return value.toString().split(".").last == rawString.toLowerCase();
    }, orElse: (){
      return null;
    });
    return type;
  }
```

Hope someone could tell me If this is possible, or there might have another approach to do this! Any information is appreciated!

Comment: These things can be solves using code generation. See built_value for example

Comment: Thansk for reminding, I found that before, but It looks hard for me, and It might cost more than copy-paste in my case :(.